# Scrapy SgmlLinkExtractor - Having trouble with recursively scraping

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

**Update: Apparently I can't answer my own question within 8 hours, but I got it to work.  Thanks guys!**

I am having trouble getting scrapy to crawl the links on the start_url.

The following is my code below:

```
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor

from dirbot.items import Website


class mydomainSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "mydomain"
    allowed_domains = ["mydomain.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.mydomain.com/cp/133162",]

    """133162 category to crawl"""

    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('133162', ), deny=('/ip/', ))),
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = hxs.select('//html')
        items = []

        for site in sites:
            item = Website()
            item['description'] = site.select('//meta[@name="Description"]/@content').extract()
            item['url'] = response.url
            item['title'] = site.xpath('/html/head/title/text()').extract()
            items.append(item)

        return items
```

I am new to python and am open to any advice.
Thank you for your time!

Comment: What exactly is your trouble? What output are you getting? An error, incorrect output?

Comment: @JasonYouk please post your answer and mark it as the correct one, this is the proper way on stackoverflow

Comment: @symbiotech, i wasn't able to to at the time.  It is now posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work, thanks guys!

```
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor

from wallspider.items import Website


class mydomainSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "mydomain"
    allowed_domains = ["www.mydomain"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.mydomain/cp/133162",]

    rules = (Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('133162', ),deny=('/ip/', 'search_sort=', 'ic=60_0', 'customer_rating', 'special_offers', ),)
    , callback="parse_items", follow= True),
    )

    def parse_items(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = hxs.select('//*')
        items = []

        for site in sites:
            item = Website()
            item['referer'] = response.request.headers.get('Referer')
            item['url'] = response.url
            item['title'] = site.xpath('/html/head/title/text()').extract()
            item['description'] = site.select('//meta[@name="Description"]/@content').extract()
            items.append(item)

        return items
```

Answer (score 0):

a few observations:

1. scrapy shell can be very useful for adjusting the right rule, to run see [How can i use scrapy shell to with parameters on url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13822582/how-can-i-use-scrapy-shell-to-with-parameters-on-url)
2. items are sent to [pipelines](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html) that should be configured in scrapy settings.py file
3. consider using `yield` instead of accumulating the items in an array

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the spider could crawl the url as you desire and the problem is how you parse the page.

What the `extract()` returns is a list, so if the type of `item['description']` and `item['title']` is not *list*, I think it will have some problems when storing those items.

The statement `sites = sel.select('//html')` seems not necessary and it may result in duplicate data.

Comment: sites = sel.select('//html') results in duplicates?  what would be a better selector?

Comment: @JasonYouk, I tested `sel.select("//html")` using `scrapy shell` and I observed that it returned two nodes. I think this statement is not important and could be omitted. Just use `sel.select(XPATH_TO_DATA_YOU_WANT)`